# Why is my Player moving Down on Screen In Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, 2d

I am not sure why but I am starting a new project in which a player moves with WASD and points towards the mouse pointer. This is all the code I have so far as It is only early into development but any help would be nice. [Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q7Tq3.png)  is a little pic of what I currently have on my player...

**ANY HELP WILL BE AMAZING!**

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class PlayerMovement : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float moveSpeed = 5f;

    public Rigidbody2D rb;

    Vector2 movement;

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        movement.x = Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal");
        movement.y = Input.GetAxisRaw("Vertical");
        Vector3 mousePosition = Input.mousePosition;
        mousePosition = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(mousePosition);
        Vector2 direction = new Vector2(
        mousePosition.x - transform.position.x,
        mousePosition.y - transform.position.y
        );
        transform.up = direction;
    }

    private void FixedUpdate()
    {
        rb.MovePosition(rb.position + movement * moveSpeed * Time.fixedDeltaTime);
    }
}
```

Comment: And your question is...? Could you please clarify which problem you have with your code?

Answer (score 0):

Set the gravity scale to 0 or set Rigidbody2D body type to Kinematic.
Kinematic rigidbodies can only be moved via script and are not participated in regular physics unlike dynamic rigidbody. So if you don't want some 'automatic' behaviors always use kinematic body type, otherwise if only problem is automatic 'moving down' issue then set gravity scale to 0 and that's all.
I think both will work in your case. And also here is some further [info](https://needoneapp.medium.com/unity-should-i-choose-kinematic-static-or-dynamic-for-rigidbody-2d-body-type-191ce65fa35f)